# How to speed up drawing graphs (charts) in Java? (own library)

Tags: java, javafx, graphics

How to write a java library that would display graphs (charts) with large datasets (100-200 thousand points)? I think that such a large graph does not need to be displayed entirely, I probably only need to display a part of it, for example, a thousand points. But I need to be able to move around the graph and scale it.
It is also necessary that the charts are built in real time. As I understand it, for any action with the chart, the data must be displayed again, that is, thereby updated.
Maybe for speed it will be possible to do parallel execution of some parts of the code for drawing the chart. Because the speed of execution will be the main thing in this library.
I also plan to convert the chart to svg to be inserted into the html page.

Now I just build a graph using `JavaFX`, and it is very slow to build on a couple of thousand points and `JavaFX` does not seem to have tools for scaling.

```java
public class FXLineChart {
    private List<Long> dataset;

    public FXLineChart(List<Long> dataset) {
        this.dataset = dataset;
    }

    public void drawChart(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Chart");
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart =
                new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("Check dataset");

        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataset.size(); i++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, dataset.get(i)));
        }

        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

`JFreeChart` is slightly better, but the chart slows down at several tens of thousands of points. I did not find information about real time in `JFreeChart`.

Maybe someone has a code for a similar task or idea? The challenge is that according to the assignment it should be its own library.

Comment: Consider rendering the graph to a backing image

Comment: @MadProgrammer, can you tell more?

Comment: A chart can only be so many pixels wide and high.  You can't display more data points than pixels.  As far as zooming, you have to write code to make that happen.  There's no automatic way to zoom in and out of a chart.  @MadProgrammer's suggestion is one idea.

Comment: Make sure you switch [animation off](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/Chart.html#setAnimated(boolean)) on the chart, that may help with performance, though perhaps not as much as you need.  It may end up that JavaFX Charts are not a good fit for your requirements and JFreeChart or an HTML-based charting solution with a WebView might work better for you. [General JavaFX performance tips](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Performance+Tips+and+Tricks),

Comment: Zooming charts is really a different question.  There is a [chart zoom example by james-d](https://gist.github.com/james-d/7252698).  I think zooming in conjunction with charts is pretty complicated and, as it isn't a core feature of the underlying charting library, any attempt to build it on top of the chart library will be pretty piecemeal and perhaps not optimal.  That's just my opinion.